# How to print arduino data one by one

Tags: arduino

I added this code (bluetooth.print("4");) in arduino ide and it will print out in phone right? But the data is 44444444444, so how to get the data like 4 not keep repeat?

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean didAlready = false;
if(!didAlready){
    bluetooth.print("4");
    didAlready = true;
}
```

That will only print the 4 once.  But this probably isn't the answer you want.  You'll have to provide a lot more detail to get anything really useful.